# Android change look of custom keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I have successfully made a very basic custom keyboard for Android based off of [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615). The problem is, this keyboard looks very odd and outdated for Android lollipop:

Image of the current keyboard:

[image]

I have been looking at other keyboards such as the default OS keyboard and this one:

[image]

And they look much better for Android.

How can I modify the color scheme and style of my keyboard to look better?

It is also worth noting I am making a keyboard that is very similar to the second example (it will just have a few extra buttons).

Comment: Please add **relevant code** or at least a **link to the tutorial**.

Comment: @F43nd1r Whoops! I thought I did. Anyway, I put the link to the tutorial and I will post some of the code soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a lot of control and be able to do things dynamically, I suggest you ditch the xml layout and KeyboardView class and make your own custom keyboard view